# Email sending limit in web-server using outlook

Tags: asp.net, web-services, email, outlook

Last week till yesterday i cannot send email using auto send in asp. I have more that 125 to 150 email address that i want to received the report. But i encounter error, so I set the original receipt and it was successfully send the email. Is their any limit in web-server in sending email in outlooks?